# How to compare the numerical with the analytical solution of PDE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization

Given the analytical solution

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x^2/2] (1 + 0.2*HermiteH[4, x] + 0.01*HermiteH[6, x])
n = 10;
A = Table[
   1/(Sqrt[Pi] 2^m m!) Integrate[
     f[x] HermiteH[m, x] Exp[x^2/2], {x, 0, 1}], {m, 1, n}];
u[x_, t_] := 
 Sum[A[[m]] Exp[-m/2 t] Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[m - 1, x], {m, 1, n}]
```

and the numerical solution

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eigen[n_] := n + 1/2
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[1]
Y[4]
Y[6]
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) - 1/2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) + 
   1/2*x^2*u[x, t] == 0
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0}
sol = First[NDSolve[{PDE, BCs, IC}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]]
```

How could I compare the two solutions with the plot command?
I face some difficulties in this particular case

Comment: How you know that `u` is exact solution for this PDE?

Comment: Plot the difference.

Comment: @DanielHuber How could I do that, please?

Comment: Look at  my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the same symbol for the analytical and numerical solution. Then move the "Clear"  to the beginning, otherwise you will clear the numerical solution. Then store a function in "sol" not a rule.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Exp[-x^2/2] (1 + 0.2*HermiteH[4, x] + 0.01*HermiteH[6, x])
n = 10;
A = Table[
   1/(Sqrt[Pi] 2^m m!) Integrate[
     f[x] HermiteH[m, x] Exp[x^2/2], {x, 0, 1}], {m, 1, n}];
ua[x_, t_] := 
 Sum[A[[m]] Exp[-m/2 t] Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[m - 1, x], {m, 1, n}]

Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x];
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n];
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6];
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x];
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) - 1/2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) + 
       1/2*x^2*u[x, t] == 0;
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0};
sol[x_, t_] = 
 u[x, t] /. 
  First[NDSolve[{PDE, BCs, IC}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]]

Plot3D[{sol[x, t] - ua[x, t]}, {x, -21, 21}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]